# currDateEnd.setHours is not a function

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to convert my date in ISO format and also set the hours to 23. This is my code:

```
var currDateEnd = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
console.log(currDateEnd);
currDateEnd.toDate().toISOString();
console.log(currDateEnd);
currDateEnd.setHours(23);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Mon Oct 19 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)

Mon Oct 19 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
```

but on the last one line I get this error:

> currDateEnd.setHours is not a function

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Running the code below:

```
var currDateEnd = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
console.log("currDateEnd iso => ", currDateEnd.toDate().toISOString());
```

produces this output:

> currDateEnd iso =>  2015-10-19T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: currDateEnd is not a date.  If you assigned the value to a variable (which you don't) currDateEnd.toDate() would be a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because setHours executes on Date objects, whereas currDateEnd is a moment object. You can do hour method of moment js and convert to ISO string after that.

```
currDateEnd.hour(23).toISOString()
```

Comment: are you using 
console.log("currDateEnd iso => ", currDateEnd.hour(23).toISOString()); ?

Comment: If I do what you propose I get ths: 2015-10-19

Comment: Well I'm sure we can optimise this, but does this work?


console.log("currDateEnd iso => ", new Date(new Date(currDateEnd).setHours(23)).toISOString());

Comment: Maybe you could take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/54488232?noredirect=1

Answer (score 4):

`currDateEnd.setHours(23);`

**should be**

`currDateEnd.toDate().setHours(23);`

as `.setHours()` can be called on a **Date object** and you have a **Moment object** `currDateEnd`, it needs to be converted.

Comment: `start` returns a Moment object that is the first visible day. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: I want set the hours to 23 from the date returned and also I want convert it into ISO format, that's it

Comment: yes but you don't have a Date object here, don't you see it?

Comment: Can you explain what value do you expect `currDateEnd` to hold initially?